# Simple way to setup Triple Boot of Win 7, Ubuntu and Fedora

Tags: system-installation

I want to do triple boot with Win 7, Ubuntu and Fedora (for the full gnome 3 experience) on my 4GB Ram 500GB HD, please show me how to do so. I want grub2 to be the default boot menu for the custom graphic features. TY. I seen this site but don't know if it is legit.

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/05/triple-boot-windows-7-ubuntu-12-10-and-fedora-18-on-one-hdd/

Comment: That link is a walk through, with screen shot of how to triple boot as you wish. What question do you have ?

Comment: Do you find everything about to be legit. How do you get the boot menu to just be grub2? dose it manner that I start with fedora then ubuntu being first?

Comment: No, no, no. The only thing that you have to do no matter what is installing Windows first, so it won't mess up your boot.

Comment: Then afterwards ubuntu or fedora?

Answer (score 1):

My steps would be:

1. Boot to Fedora flash drive
2. Shrink Windows partition using installer
3. Create a root partition for Fedora following the Windows partition (leave room for Ubuntu!)
4. Create a swap partition at the end of the disk (4-8GB should be enough)
5. Install Fedora on its partition
6. Reboot to Ubuntu flash drive
7. Create Ubuntu root partition in the remaining space
8. Use the swap partition you created earlier for Ubuntu swap as well, by selecting the "Use as" option, and selecting "swap"
9. Install Ubuntu on its root partition
10. Reboot! Ubuntu should have detected Fedora and Windows and set up GRUB accordingly.

You should end up with the following partitions in this order:

- Windows partitions
- Fedora root partition
- Ubuntu root partition
- Swap partition

Comment: Do I have to do any shell configurations? like it was said in the link. @Brian B.

Comment: Should I just create more partitons since I was thinking of giving it (fedora) 25GB space

Comment: No, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Okay so your saying I could just create one large partition window side and on that large partition it can be shared among both distros? and so far as the command line config. TY so much!!!!! it makes sence!!! :)

Comment: should I use the window partition-er to create space for root and swap or I can do that on fedora install? what would be a suggested amount for Fedora and Ubuntu?

Comment: One swap partition can be shared between Fedora and Ubuntu, but NOT their root paritions, which should be separate. To clarify, I meant the shell configurations would not be necessary. I would split the space after your Windows partition equally between Ubuntu and Fedora, at least 30GB each. You can use the Fedora installer to do all your partitioning.

Comment: I made a mistake. I had partition 62 GB of space before actually this post and now as I tried to establish root, It wont let me. It detected the partition and wanted to use all of it even though I wanted to give it half. Should I delete it and do it from Fedora? or re-size the 62 GB into half for it?

Comment: Even automatic is problem-matic, it keeps saving not enough disk space.

Comment: You can resize it or delete it and create a smaller one and reinstall. Either works.

Comment: Do you suggest I do it from windows partition software or fedora. I don't have live boot and i am not sure whether they have such an option for the install iso.

Comment: Fedora, Linux is usually better at recognizing all types of partitions.